# Configuring fixture_path in ActiveRecord test fixtures

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord with Sinatra instead of Rails, and I want to use fixtures in my tests. The documentation for [ActiveRecord's FixtureSet](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet) says that you have to use `fixture_path` to tell it where the fixture files are:

> placed in the directory appointed by ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path=(path)

How can I write to that setting? I tried `@fixture_path` and `@@fixture_path`, but both of them left the value nil when `FixtureSet` tried to read it.

Here's the only thing I could get to work, but it can't possibly be right:

```
# test_helper.rb
require_relative '../app'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)

#Set up fixtures and such
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveRecord::TestFixtures
  include ActiveRecord::TestFixtures::ClassMethods

  class << self
    def fixtures(*fixture_set_names)
      self.fixture_path = 'test/fixtures'
      super *fixture_set_names
    end
  end

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
end
```

The full source code is posted as a [small demo project](https://github.com/donkirkby/active_sinatra) for ActiveRecord and Sinatra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to leave this as a comment on your answer, but it got too long so I thought I might as put it in an answer.

The reason `@fixture_path` and `@@fixture_path` didn't work is that `fixture_path` is an ActiveSupport [class attribute](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#class-attributes), which is like a Ruby `attr_accessor` except it's defined as a singleton method on the class. You can see where the `fixture_path` attribute is defined with `class_attribute :fixture_path` in the [ActiveRecord::TestFixtures module source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ea4f0e2baba8653b03fba154357842933cf7b778/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L862).

Class attributes are part of ActiveSupport and not native to Ruby. You can read more about them in the [Active Support Core Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#class-attributes) Rails Guide and in the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-class_attribute), and see how `class_attribute` works [in the Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e5e42a3687801a1dc1c3e36ea784a7a1479a9230/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb#L71). As you can see, 
the value is stored in the instance variable `"@#{name}"` (e.g. `@fixture_path`), but that happens inside a singleton method, which means it's an instance variable on the singleton class and you can only access it from within the singleton class.

That's all a little bit moot, though, because the point of attributes (and feel free to disregard this if it's old news to you) is that they allow you to keep instance variables private and change your implementation without breaking code that subclasses or includes your code. When an attribute reader or writer exists, you should always use it instead of accessing the instance variable directly, because at some point the implementation might change and the attribute methods could be replaced by methods with more complex logic, and accessing the instance variable directly will no longer produce the same results as using the attribute reader and writer.

As you discovered, you need to use `self.fixture_path =` instead of `fixture_path =` because in the latter case Ruby assumes you want to assign to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had noticed the `class_attribute`, but hadn't put it all together.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe I didn't see this, but I didn't. I had to use `self`, just like the settings for transactional fixtures and instantiated fixtures.

```
# test_helper.rb
require_relative '../app'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)

#Set up fixtures and such
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveRecord::TestFixtures
  include ActiveRecord::TestFixtures::ClassMethods

  self.fixture_path = 'test/fixtures'
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
end
```

The trick is understanding the meaning of `self` in a class definition; it refers to the class, not an instance of the class. I guess when I'm monkey patching `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, that's the only way to set a class variable. For some reason `@fixture_path` and `@@fixture_path` don't work.